# iPod Touch thinks it's full when it isn't

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, data-synchronization

I just got a refurbished iPod Touch.  I synced it to my work computer rather than my Mac at home because it is mainly for PodCasts.  It was working great, until I put my music on iTunes over a network share at home and accidentally told the iPod Touch to sync all music.
Ever since then, every time I try to sync my iPod Touch it tells me that it does not have enough space to sync all the data I am trying to sync.
The problem with that, is I'm only trying to sync about 30 total Podcasts, all of which are audio and none are longer than an hour.

I have reset the iPod to factory settings and still get the same thing.

In fact, I just told it (after a restore to factory settings) to sync nothing.  Literally unchecked every sync option in iTunes and it is still telling me I have too much data being synced.

The iPod itself tells me that it has 6.5gigs of free space, but iTunes says I have 15.7 gigs of Music synced to it.

Anyone seen this before or have any idea what I can do?

Comment: I have the same problem with my iPad, but I'm guessing it's because I'm using a beta OS. Are you using 4.3.3 or 5 beta?

Comment: Nope.  4.3.2 I think.

Comment: Do you have the error after restoring the device and setting up as new. Only sync one song or short playlist that clearly is less than 1 or 2 Gb total. This will show if the error is on the device or in the iTunes library.

Comment: Yep, I have completely restored the device and told it to sync nothing but a single podcast, I also tried syncing nothing at all, neither works.  I can download podcasts to the device from iTunes ON the device, but iTunes on my computer says it is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uummmm....I figured it out....
under the Books tab, the "Sync Audiobooks" option was checked....but it was below the visible portion of the screen so I didn't realize it was checked until my network drive with my audio books got disconnected and on an attempted sync it said it couldn't find the files.

OOPS!!!  I feel sheepish.